# No internet on new wireless network on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I've just added a wireless network connection to a Windows 7 PC - like I've added several in the past but I always stumble through it - and it connects to the network, but with no internet access.  I used Network and Sharing Center wizards etc. all the way.  Pretty much did the same with my laptop on the same network and I have access, so I suspect its something specific to that machine.

Comment: Can you open cmd and do an IPConfig and post the results here. This will help people diagnose possible problems.

Comment: @Joe, yes, I will do when I am back at the client tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ping 127.0.0.1. Is ping successful?
Ping 192.168.1.1. Is ping successful?

Try resetting the router and modem. I assume you know how to do this so I won't bother you with the details.

Did you use DHCP to configure the IP address, or did you assign a static IP address?

Comment: Pinging 192.168.1.1 would fail unless the router is at that address. I know its common but just dishing out that advice may prove unhelpful. Getting him to check the gateway address in ipconfig and then pinging that would be helpful. And pinging the loopback address? Why?

Comment: @Joe Taylor, if you ping the loopback address, doesn't it verify that the TCP/ IP protocol is functioning on the NIC? Since there is no actual physical link to the loopback interface, you don't have to consider faulty ethernet cables as a cause IF the ping was unsuccessful. On the other hand, if a ping to the router/ gateway was unsuccessful, you'd have to find the cause which could indeed be TCP/ IP protocol not functioning, faulty ethernet cable, faulty router, etc. Am I wrong in any of this? Please let me know.

Comment: You would only ping 192.168.1.1 if that was the router / gateway address. Some would have it as 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.0.254 etc. The idea is correct, just the wording leaves room for error. Loopback is a good idea with your reasoning.

Comment: @Joe Taylor: Yes. I understand what you mean about the router's IP, completely. I should have definitely worded that differently. Thanks Joe.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess, you have static or incorrect addresses configured on the your wireless adapter. Check your TCP/IP settings for the wireless adapter. Make sure it set to auto config if your router is setup up for DHCP. Otherwise make sure the settings are correct if you manually entered the static addresses.